# Not able to access zabbix default port (10050) in a server that contains VPN installed

Tags: vpn, zabbix, ubuntu-18.04, ipsec, strongswan

I want to monitor the server that contains VPN(strongswan) installed using zabbix.

From my Zabbix server it is not able to access the zabbix client installed in my VPN server. Is their any way to open zabbix default port 10050?

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

command output shows:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip


To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
10050/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
10050                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
10050/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
10050 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its better to use Iptables rule, below command will allow zabbix server ip in tcp mode.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s <zabbix server ip>  --dport 10050 -j ACCEPT
```